# Android: How can I set my custom surfaceview to a fixed size ratio in xml?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am trying to have a surfaceview (a custom class which extends surfaceview) that I add in the xml layout to have a fixed size ratio: 4:3 (length to width).

I want it to fill as much as it can of it's parent, either on the length or width but once it reaches the full length or width it will adjust the other side to have a fixed size ratio like I said before.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to make it in the xml layout instead, and later read the resolution given by the class.

Answer (score 5):

In the onCreate method of your activity you could read the resolution of the screen and set the layout width and height to it.

Example assuming you're using RealtiveLayout:

```
private void create43RatioSurface() {
    SurfaceView surfaceView43 = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;

    if(metrics.widthPixels < metrics.heightPixels){
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height= (metrics.widthPixels/4) * 3 ;
    } else {
        height= metrics.heightPixels;
        width= (metrics.heightPixels/4) * 3 ;
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    surfaceView43.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);        
}
```

Comment: It's easy to make dynamically, but I am trying to have a way do it in xml, and once it has it's size already, I'll just find the scale ratio and draw everything in the canvas accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This might be kind of hacky but you could maybe put a blank imageview as a sort of frame for the surfaceview.  Now to explain the madness

> 1)Create an image asset that fits the proportion you want that is all
>   transparent.  Lets call tis our ghost image (probably best to make it
>   invisible as well)
>
> 2)use a relative layout and place the imageview in the relative layout
>   with match_parent for height and width and using scaletype
>   CENTER_INSIDE or CENTER_CROP if you went van gocha and created a
>   massive asset
>
> 3)add your surface view to the layout after the imageview and
>   aligntop/bottom/right/left with the image view

I haven't tried this implementation but it should give you the ratio you want for whatever screen you have.